# SQL: How to insert/update multiple tables by checking duplicates in one table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

MS SQL: I want to insert/update data in a table based on below conditions.

[image]

I have tried using IF EXISTS as shown below. Can anyone correct me if I'm wrong here or send an alternative one which does this job better?

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from TableA where col1 in (select col1 from tableA))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT * FROM TableB 
WHERE some condition

DELETE FROM TableB
WHERE some condition

DELETE l FROM TableC l
INNER JOIN #temptable s on l.col1 = s.col1 WHERE l.col1 = s.col1
END

ELSE 
BEGIN
UPDATE TableA set (columns which are changed in TableA) where condition which pulls up exisiting query
END
```

Comment: You should do this as a trigger, not a programming block -- unless this is a one time exercise.  If this code is in a stored procedure, two threads could call it at the same time, resulting in unpredictable outcomes.

Comment: `select 1 from TableA where col1 not in (select col1 from tableA)`... Surely this has no results...

Comment: @GordonLinoff, This procedure will run every day. Do you mean I should use an insert trigger?

Comment: @JohnHC, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple using new MERGE operator provide in sql server 2008. 
In MERGE operation you can define source and target table and based on matching and un-matching rows you can perform delete , update or insert in one shot.
please refer below link for more detail - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/